# Flutter Build_Runner Build Failing While Generating Floor

Tags: flutter, build-runner, flutter-floor

build failed after flutter upgrade.

```
$ flutter pub run build_runner build
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 331ms

[WARNING] ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/floor_generator-1.4.1/lib/misc/type_utils.dart:25:26: Error: The getter 'element' isn't defined for the class 'DartType'.
 - 'DartType' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-5.0.0/lib/dart/element/type.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'element'.
  bool get isEnumType => element is EnumElement;
```

how to fix it ?

form pubspec.yaml:

floor_generator: ^1.4.1

build_runner: ^2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run `flutter pub get` after your flutter upgrade. Then `flutter pub cache repair`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by adding a line to pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: ^5.4.0
```